# awk command prints first column value as 1

Tags: awk

I am trying print column 1 and 5 if value in column 5 is available and column 1 & 2  values are equal and column 3 & 4 values are equal.
For the above I am using below command.

```
awk 'length($5) && $1=$2 && $3=$4 {print $1" "$5}' filename
```

Below is my file have below content

```
343 222 222 333 333 test
565 444 444 555 555 testi
234 121 121 454 454 
345 676 676 343 343 testin
```

But I am getting first column value as 1, output will be like below

```
1 test
1 testi
1 testin
```

I have 3 conditions in the my command, if I use 2 condition it is working fine.
Can any one explain me why I am getting it as 1 and how to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

`=` is an assignment.  Use `==` to compare values.  You get `1` because you essentially have `$1 = ($2 && $3 = $4)`.

```
awk 'NF == 5 && $1 == $2 && $3 == $4 { print $1, $5 }' filename
```

Also note that your data contains 5 or 6 columns, not 4 or 5, so maybe you meant to use

```
$ awk 'NF == 6 && $2 == $3 && $4 == $5 { print $1, $6 }' filename
343 test
565 testi
345 testin
```

`NF` is an `awk` variable that contains the number of fields in the current record.  The default output separator (`OFS`) is a space, so there's no need to print an explicit space with `print`.

Also, if you had wanted to print an explicit space, it would have been more readable to do

```
print $1 " " $6
```

rather than

```
print $1" "$6
```

`awk` concatenates the values of variables and strings when they occur after each other.  The spaces between the variables and strings do not matter.

Answer (score 0):

```
Command: awk '{if ((length($6) >0) && ($2==$3) && ($4==$5)) {print $1,$6}}'  filename
```

output

veen_linux_example ~]#

```
 awk '{if ((length($6) >0) && ($2==$3) && ($4==$5)) {print $1,$6}}' filename

343 test
565 testi
345 testin
```